# Base for an isotropic space

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I'm currently working on an exercise which is about finding the base of an isotropic space $(V,\beta)$
The space $V$ is equipped with a symmetric bilinear form $\beta$ and together they form the so called metric space $(V,\beta)$.

I know that
\begin{equation}
V = V_\bot \oplus H \oplus W
\end{equation}
Where 
\begin{equation}
H = \oplus^{m}_{i=1} H_i
\end{equation}
And the $H_i$ are the so called hyperbolic planes which have the proberty that their structure matrix - in regard to a basis containing of an isotropic vector $u_i$ and a proper corresponding vector $v_i$- take the form:
\begin{bmatrix}
0&&1\\1&&0
\end{bmatrix}

So far so good. For my concrete example I have the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&5&0&0\\0&0&3&1&0\\5&3&2&1&3\\0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&3&0&0\end{bmatrix}
which corresponds to a bilinear form $\beta:V\times V \to K$ where $V=K^5$ and $K=\mathbb{Z}/{7\mathbb{Z}}$.

Step 1: Giving a base for $V_{\bot}=\operatorname{Rad}(V,\beta)$. That's easy, we immediately see, that $v=(5,0,0,0,1)$ fulfils the condition
\begin{equation}
\forall w \in V: \beta(v,w) = 0 
\end{equation}
So: 
\begin{equation}
V_\bot = span\{v\}
\end{equation}
Step 2: Giving a base for the orthogonal complement of $V_\bot$. My attempt (which seems to be wrong) was just simply to take for example 
\begin{equation}
B = (e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)
\end{equation}
as a basis.

The corresponding structure matrix would then clearly be just the structure matrix before with cut off fifth column and row.

Step 3 & 4: Here is where it becomes tricky. I now want to determine the isotropic vectors $u_i$. I.e the vectors which fulfill the relation
\begin{equation}
\beta_1(u_i,u_i)=0.
\end{equation}
Where $\beta_1$ is the restriction I explained above.
Clearly one sees that for example $e_1,e_4$ are both isotropic vectors.
For I know that the space of isotropic vectors has dimension less than 3 (if I have two isotropic vectors the corresponding hyperbolic space has clearly dimension 4) I would have been done.

The only step left would be to find vectors $v_i$ which fulfill
\begin{equation}
(i): \beta(u_i,v_j)=\delta_{i,j}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
(ii): \beta(v_i,v_j)= 0
\end{equation}
Of course the vectors $u_1,v_1,u_2,v_2$ have to be lineary indepent as they give us a base for the hyperbolic subspace.
To visualice the corresponding structure matrix would be
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

I don't find vectors $v_i$ which fulfill this relations. Anyone out there who could tell me, what I was doing wrong.

Comment: What book is this from? In particular, it is hard to see why anyone would call $(V, \beta)$ a metric space.

Comment: It's no book. It's from my lectures. The problem was quiet easy, I solved it a day later.

Comment: @simon.v In that case, you might post your solution here as an answer. (The question might be useful for other users.)

Comment: One has just to use ALL the conditions I described (this was my mistake at first) and than solve the corresponding equations.